# Assertion of void asynchronous method

Tags: c#, testing

I have a class similiar to this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Task MyMethod()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

As described, 'MyMethod' is asynchronous, lets say for simplicity that this is it's implementation:

```
    public Task MyMethod()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var success = _someService.DoSomething();
            if (!success) throw new Exception("unsuccsesfull");
        });

    }
```

Obviously, when MyMethod awaitable callback will run it means that no exception was thrown in the running thread, meaning 'MyMethod' invocation was successfull.

I want to test this method. The test method to will look like:

```
[Test]
public async void TestMyMethod_TestInitialState_TestExpectedResult()
{
    // test initialization..
    //...
    //..
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    await myClass.MyMethod();

    Assert.That(????)
}
```

My question - what is the correct assertion?

I have a possible solution - add a logical member to 'MyClass' and update this member according to the method result:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool SomeMember { get; private set; }

    public Task MyMethod()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {               
            SomeMember = _someService.DoSomething();
            if (!SomeMember ) throw new Exception("unsuccsesfull");
        });

    }
}
```

That way I can assert the test like this:

```
    [Test]
    public async void TestMyMethod_TestInitialState_SomeMemberShouldBeTrue()
    {
        // test initialization..
        //...
        //..
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        await myClass.MyMethod();

        Assert.True(SomeMember)
    }
}
```

However, I dont like this solution because I'm adding a property to 'MyClass' just to be able to assert a test, I dont really need this property in my bussiness world. Also each property added to a class represents some state of this class and adds a level of comlexity.

Suggestions?

Guy.

Comment: Well presumably the asynchronous operation has some effect - otherwise it would be pointless executing it. What's it doing, and can you test that it's happened?

Comment: In my case it sends a file the another computer. This is done by exchaning communication messages and invloves a TFTP server from which the other machine requesting the file from. I will know about the success of this process by a communication message I will receive from that machine indicating the file is in its poession. I dont control when this notification message will arrive, hence the asynchronous interface I'm exspoing

Comment: So what does it do in your test situation? Presumably it's not actually doing TFTP in that case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want what's called a "mock" or "stub". The idea is that you refactor your code so that it has a dependency on an interface, then you mock the interface while testing.

There are various frameworks/tools that help out with mocking (Moq, Microsoft Fakes, TypeMock Isolator, JustMock, etc), and there are also many frameworks that help out with the closely related problem of dependency injection (Unity, Castle Windsor, StructureMap, Autofac, etc).

But you can start off just doing it yourself. First, refactor `MyClass` so it depends on `ISomeService`:

```
public interface ISomeService
{
  bool DoSomething();
}

public class MyClass
{
  private readonly ISomeService _someService;

  public MyClass(ISomeService someService)
  {
    _someService = someService;
  }

  public Task MyMethod()
  {
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
      var success = _someService.DoSomething();
      if (!success) throw new Exception("unsuccsesfull");
    });
  }
}
```

Then in your unit test:

```
private class TestService : ISomeService
{
  public bool DoSomethingReturnValue { get; set; }

  public bool DoSomething() { return DoSomethingReturnValue; }
}

[Test]
public async Task TestMyMethod_TestInitialState_TestExpectedResult()
{
  var myClass = new MyClass(new TestService { DoSomethingReturnValue = true });
  await myClass.MyMethod();
}

[Test]
public async Task TestMyMethod_TestInitialState_TestFailure()
{
  var myClass = new MyClass(new TestService { DoSomethingReturnValue = false });
  Assert.Throws(() => myClass.MyMethod()); // (I'm unsure of the exact NUnit syntax)
}
```

Comment: althoug I didnt asked about mocking I think your answer fit my reqiuerments.. thanks!